# Pandas: Converting Multiple Columns at once corrupts Data but individually does not?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Feeling like an idiot right now, but I can't get anything but the most hackey solution to the below problem working.

I have a dataframe with 3 distinct "sections".

1. The first is 13 columns of Serial Number Data, each column is a single ASCII Code. These columns are captured in the list `[serialname_list]`
2. Columns of "core data" that is present on every row
3. Columns of "additional data" that is only present on 80% of all rows

Dataframe roughly looks like:

```
   sn1  sn2  ...  sn13  data1  data2   add1  add2  
0   74   79   76   66   5.0     5.0     NaN   NaN   
1   81   66   89   65   1.0     1.0     NaN   NaN   
2   82   81   78   66   2.0     2.0     79    80
```

I'm writing a function to convert the 13 ASCII codes into actual ASCII characters, then combine them into a single field and remove the individual columns. Some of the "SN" fields are corrupted with obviously wrong float values, in those cases I just remove any row that has non-standard data.

I'm running into an issue in converting the ASCII codes. Previously I was using:

`df[serialname_list] = df[serialname_list].apply(lambda x: x.map(chr))`

However, I noticed that when this line runs, the DF was deleting all of the "additional data" columns, as well as any row where the "additional data" was NaN.

Trying different methods of an aggregate function on the fields defined in `[serialname_list]` always replicated this issue (I.E. apply(map), replace, etc...). Directly referencing the 13 columns and applying the conversion function works fine however.

What am I missing, what is the proper way to do this without listing each field name individually?

```
def convertserial(df):
    
    def chr_convert(x):
        y = chr(x)
        return y
    
    msk = df[serialname_list].lt(1).any(axis=1) #Mask where any sn column is less than 1, real data not ASCII
    idx_to_drop = df.index[msk] #Create indicies based on mask
    df = df.drop(idx_to_drop) #drop based on the index
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    df[serialname_list]=df[serialname_list].astype(int)
    
    df['sn1'] = df['sn1'].apply(chr_convert)
    df['sn2'] = df['sn2'].apply(chr_convert)
    df['sn3'] = df['sn3'].apply(chr_convert)
    df['sn4'] = df['sn4'].apply(chr_convert)
    df['sn5'] = df['sn5'].apply(chr_convert)
    df['sn6'] = df['sn6'].apply(chr_convert)
    df['sn7'] = df['sn7'].apply(chr_convert)
    df['sn8'] = df['sn8'].apply(chr_convert)
    df['sn9'] = df['sn9'].apply(chr_convert)
    df['sn10'] = df['sn10'].apply(chr_convert)
    df['sn11'] = df['sn11'].apply(chr_convert)
    df['sn12'] = df['sn12'].apply(chr_convert)
    df['sn13'] = df['sn13'].apply(chr_convert)
    #df[serialname_list] = df[serialname_list].apply(chr_convert)
    df.insert(0, "serial", df.apply(
        lambda x: f"{x['sn1']}{x['sn2']}{x['sn3']}{x['sn4']+'-'+x['sn5']+x['sn6']+x['sn7']+x['sn8']+'-'+x['sn9']+x['sn10']+x['sn11'] if x['sn4'] == 'A' else '-'+x['sn4']+x['sn5']+x['sn6']+x['sn7']+'-'+x['sn8']+x['sn9']+x['sn10']}",
        axis=1
        ))
    
    df.insert(1,"position",  df.apply(
        lambda x: f"{x['sn12']+x['sn13'] if x['sn4'] == 'A' else x['sn11']+x['sn12']}",
        axis=1
        ))
    
    df.drop(columns=serialname_list[:],inplace=True)
    
    return df
```

Comment: `serialname_list` is defined like `serialname_list = ['sn1', 'sn2', ..., 'sn13']`, right?

Comment: Yes that is how it is defined. A list of strings of the col names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `.apply(…, axis=1)` for string operations in `pandas` that need to rely on functionalities that only exist on the Python side of things (e.g. formatting across columns).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sn1': [65, 66, 67],
    'sn2': [68, 69, 70],
    'sn3': [71, 72, 73],
    'sn4': [74, 75, 76],
    'sn5': [77, 78, 79],
    'y': [10, 11, 12]
})

df['serial'] = (
    df.filter(like='sn')
    .applymap(chr) # .applymap for pandas < 2.1.0 OR .map for pandas >= 2.1.0

    # format across multiple columns
    .apply('({sn1})({sn2})-{sn3}:{sn4}-{sn5}'.format_map, axis=1)
)

print(df)
#    sn1  sn2  sn3  sn4  sn5   y        serial
# 0   65   68   71   74   77  10  (A)(D)-G:J-M
# 1   66   69   72   75   78  11  (B)(E)-H:K-N
# 2   67   70   73   76   79  12  (C)(F)-I:L-O
```

---

`DataFrame.apply(…, axis=0)` (note that `axis=0` is the default) passes each Series to the function specified. Each of the Series objects are then joined to a new resultant `DataFrame`.

```py
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__) # 1.5.3

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sn1': [65, 66, 67],
    'sn2': [68, 69, 70],
    'sn3': [71, 72, 73],
    'sn4': [74, 75, 76],
    'sn5': [77, 78, 79],
    'y': [10, 11, 12]
})

snlist = ['sn1', 'sn2', 'sn3']
df[snlist] = df[snlist].apply(lambda s: s.map(chr))

print(df)
#   sn1 sn2 sn3  sn4  sn5   y
# 0   A   D   G   74   77  10
# 1   B   E   H   75   78  11
# 2   C   F   I   76   79  12
```

If the above doesn't work for you, it could be due to some difference in our `pandas.__version__`.

Comment: Got this working with ```df[serialname_list] = df[serialname_list].applymap(chr)``` based on your suggestion. I still don't understand why ```df[serialname_list] = df[serialname_list].apply(lambda x: x.map(chr))``` didn't work and had such strange behavior. Does lambda not respect the columns I tried to limit it to?

Comment: just added a second segment, the snippet you've shared works for me in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code using .map with simplified data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [65, 66, 67],
                   'x2': [68, 69, 70],
                   'x3': [71, 72, 73],
                   'y': [10, 11, 12]
                   })

x_list = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']

df[x_list] = df[x_list].map(chr)

print(df)
```

gives

```
 x1 x2 x3   y
0  A  D  G  10
1  B  E  H  11
2  C  F  I  12
```

and to join the characters:

```
df['x'] = pd.Series(map(''.join, df[x_list].values.astype(str).tolist()))
```

giving:

```
  x1 x2 x3   y    x
0  A  D  G  10  ADG
1  B  E  H  11  BEH
2  C  F  I  12  CFI
```

Comment: I get an error, DataFrame has no attribute 'map'

Comment: You must be using an older version of Pandas. Either update or use `.applymap` instead. (.applymap was deprecated in later versions and the functionality transferred to .map)